# Can I use a regular expression to extract the domain from a URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, url

Suppose I want to turn this :

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchy
```

into this :

```
en.wikipedia.org
```

or even better, this :

```
wikipedia.org
```

Is this even possible in regex?

Comment: So, you want to parse out the domain from a URL?

Comment: is en always in the string? if not then you can do something like (en\.)? to say it's an optional match

Comment: You might want to clarify how general your solution needs to be and if there is a reason you don't want to use the standard URL parsing library.

Comment: Here's a good place to experiment with it, if you must use a regex http://rubular.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why use a regex when Ruby has a library for it?  [The URI library](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/URI.html#M004807):

```
ruby-1.9.1-p378 > require 'uri'
 => true 
ruby-1.9.1-p378 > uri = URI.parse("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchy")
 => #<URI::HTTP:0x000001010a2270 URL:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchy> 
ruby-1.9.1-p378 > uri.host
 => "en.wikipedia.org" 
ruby-1.9.1-p378 > uri.host.split('.')
 => ["en", "wikipedia", "org"]
```

Splitting the host is one way to separate the domains, but I'm not aware of a *reliable* way to get the base domain -- you can't just count, in the event of a URL like "http://somedomain.otherdomain.school.ac.uk" vs "www.google.com".

Comment: under the hood it's the same regex but surely you better use the library

Answer (score 2):

`/http:\/\/([^\/]*).*/` will produce en.wikipedia.org from the string you provided.

`/http:\/\/.{0,3}\.([^\/]*).*/` will produce wikipedia.org.

Comment: /^http:\/\/\w+\.(\w+\.\w+)/ 
would limit it more to the type of characters you'd want.

Comment: True. I might leave off the ^ though. If we're making it as general as possible, it might be better to match on any occurrence of a url

Answer (score 1):

yes

Now I know you haven't asked for how, and you haven't specified a language, but I'll answer anyway... (note, this works for all language subsites, not just en.wikipedia...)

perl:

```
$url =~ s,http://[a-z]{2}\.(wikipedia\.org)/.*,$1,;
```

ruby:

```
url = url.sub(/http:\/\/[a-z]{2}\.(wikipedia\.org)\/.*/, '\1')
```

php:
    $url = preg_replace('|http://[a-z]{2}.(wikipedia.org)/.*|, '$1', $url);

Of course, for this particular example, you don't even need a regex, just this will do:

```
url = 'wikipedia.org'
```

but I jest...

you probably want to handle any URL and pull out the domain part, and it should also work for domains in different countries, eg: `foo.co.uk`.

In which case, I'd use Mark Rushakoff's solution to get the hostname and then a regex to pull out the domain:

```
domain = host.sub(/^.*\.([^.]+\.[^.]+(\.[a-z]{2})?)$/, '\1')
```

Hope this helps

Also, if you want to learn more, I have a regex tute online: http://tech.bluesmoon.info/2006/04/beginning-regular-expressions.html

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could use , instead of / for perl in regex, also what does the {2} mean?

Comment: you can use any character that isn't a-z A-Z 0-9 or whitespace.  You could even use nested braces like this:

    `s{http://[a-z]{2}\.(wikipedia\.org)/.*}{$1};`

you're not even required to use the same braces for the match and the replace:

    `s{http://[a-z]{2}\.(wikipedia\.org)/.*}<$1>;`

the `{2}` means match exactly twice.

Answer (score 0):

Sure all you would have to do is search on http://(.*)/wiki/Anarchy

In Perl (Sorry I don't know Ruby, but I expect it's similar)

$string_to_search =~ s/http:////(.*)//.* should give you wikipedia.org
to get rid of the en, you can simply search on http:////en(.*)//.*.....

That should do it.

Update: In case you're not familiar with Regex, I would recommend picking up a Regex book, this one really rocks and I like it: REGEX BOOK,Mastering Regular Expressions, I saw it on half.com the other day for 14.99 used, but to clarify what i suggested above, is to look for the string http://en, then for anything until you find a / this is all captured in $1 (in perl, not sure if it's the same in ruby), a simple print $1 will print the string.

Update: #2 sorry the star in the regex is not showing up for some reason, so where you see the . in the () and after the // just imagine a *, oh and I forgot for the en part add a /. at the end that way you don't end up with .wikipedia.org